# SpringBoot ignoring security settings in application.properties

Tags: spring-boot

I'm trying to secure a simple SpringBoot application using the properties defined in application.properties.
I have added at the bottom of my application.properties:

```
security.user.name = user
security.user.password = password
```

When starting the application I can see in the logs that a default password is being generated:

```
Using generated security password: 7382afa7-aab1-4476-8ea7-aa3b2a9c51d6
```

When I try to access the Web application I can see that the credentials in application.properties are ignored. On the other hand the generated security password is still used. am I missing something?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are missing the "spring" namespace in the property file.
Check with this:

```
spring.security.user.password=password
spring.security.user.name=user
```